# I have this issue while inserting a new record in firebaseFirestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add new record in Firebase FireStore and i get this exception

```
E/flutter (11243): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(firebase_core, java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Firestore component is not present., null, null)
E/flutter (11243): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
E/flutter (11243): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:177:18)
E/flutter (11243): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11243): #2      MethodChannel.invokeListMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:363:35)
E/flutter (11243): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11243): #3      MethodChannelFirebase._initializeCore (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:31:23)
E/flutter (11243): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11243): #4      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:73:7)
E/flutter (11243): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11243): #5      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:42:31)
E/flutter (11243): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11243): #6      main (package:uccd_etu/main.dart:10:3)
E/flutter (11243): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11243):
```

this is my main.dart code

```
void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
       options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

and this is the method that will create a new record in firestore database
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

```
class DbServices {

  static DbServices instance = DbServices();
  late FirebaseFirestore _db;

  String _usersCollection = "users";

  DbServices() {
    _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  }

  Future<void> createUserInDb(String _uid,String _userName, String _nationalId,
      bool _isDisabled, String _password) async{
 try{
      return await _db.collection(_usersCollection).doc(_uid).set({
      "userName":_userName,
      "password":_password,
      "nationalId":_nationalId,
      "isDisabled":_isDisabled,
      "timeOfRegistiration":DateTime.now().toUtc()
    });
 }catch(e){print(e);}
  }



}
```

=======================
flutter doctor output

@
mdobrucki

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1256], locale ar-EG)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.8.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.64.2)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: Can you share output of `flutter doctor` and your dependencies file? I found similar issue [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28745#issuecomment-480651580), and the fix seems to be running command `flutter clean` and fixing dependencies. Let me know if it is helpful.

Comment: @ mdobrucki i added it bro , and i did flutter clean and nothing work , i think that this issue cuz of firebase not flutter sdk

Comment: Can you share your `pubspec.yml`? Are you using AndroidX?

Answer (score 0):

the exception applies to a local account who has been removed from their payment handler...the problem needs to be solved with code that identifies the exception parameters, thus handles the cookie payment, and encryption key fingerprint validated with the cookie identifying the user-agent, user, or supervisor. the manager should be you, if you're developing for this kind of exception, and the user should be 'me', owner, or first person to third party apple webkit.

Comment: so this error will disappear if i used another google account , or what should i do , please help me bro